# How to select icons in windows application using Pywinauto

Tags: click, icons, simulate, pywinauto

I am trying to simulate clicks on icons on a windows application.
Currently, only way for me to do this is to simulate mouse click using ClickInput(coords = (x,y))
The problem with above method is that whenever the software UI gets updated, its position changes which forces me to update all the scripts according to the new icon location.

Is there a way to simulate click on icons in toolstrip without using coords?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! As I know an image looks like `Static` in `pywinauto`.

```
Access names : ['Static4']
Class : Static
ClientRects : [<RECT L0, T0, R24, B24>]
ContextHelpID : 0
ControlCount : 0
ControlID : 269
ExStyle : 4
Fonts : [<LOGFONTW 'MS Shell Dlg' -11>]
FriendlyClassName : Static
handle : 2097378
Image : <Image._ImageCrop image mode=RGB size=24x24 at 0x1E47DC8>
IsEnabled : True
IsUnicode : True
IsVisible : True
MenuItems : []
pwa_type : <class 'pywinauto.controls.win32_controls.StaticWrapper'>
Rectangle : (L514, T498, R538, B522)
Style : 1342179331
Texts : ['']
UserData : 0
```

you may access it easily

```
window['Static4'].Click()
```